# Tableview cell text label not contain all String

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uilabel, custom-cell

i want to make a dynamic height label in my UITableView custom Cell for this i write a code lile as

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifierTwo=@"CellThree";
    LargeTableViewCell *cellThree=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifierTwo];
    if (cellThree == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nibTwo=[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"LargeTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cellThree=[nibTwo objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    {
        cellThree.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        NSString *str = [[self.jsonDictionary valueForKey:@"review"]objectAtIndex:0];
        CGRect frame = [str boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(288, CGFLOAT_MAX)
                                          options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                       attributes:nil
                                          context:nil];
        cellThree.largeTextView.frame = frame;
        cellThree.contentView.layer.cornerRadius=4.0f;
        if (![self.jsonDictionary isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])
        {
            cellThree.largeTextView.text=[[self.jsonDictionary valueForKey:@"review"]objectAtIndex:0];
        }
    }
    [cellThree layoutSubviews];
    return cellThree;
  }
```

and tableview `heightForRowAtIndexPath` method like as

```
NSString *str = [[self.jsonDictionary valueForKey:@"review"]objectAtIndex:0];
    CGRect frame = [str boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(288, CGFLOAT_MAX)
                                     options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                  attributes:nil
                                     context:nil];
    return frame.size.height+50;
```

then i got my tableview cell height as i want but my table view cell not contain all my parsing string it contain only some later please give me solution for  it.
Here my JsonDictionary output code like as

```
<p>The potential of a geographically mobile spirit is vast. When Ravi Babu (playing the spirit) made a surreptitious visit to the police station eavesdropping on Mohinis (Poorna) complaint, comfortably seated next to her, it was clear that the spirit was here to say as its freedom of movement cant be restricted by whatever means. In Avunu-2, it (or, should we say he because the spirit is a rapist?) arrives on the scene using the elevator and enters the new, upscale apartment through the main door.    </p><p>The migration-capable rapist-spirit is also tech-savvy and nothing can stop him except an amulet made in Varanasi. The characters at the receiving end, too, are the same, with an addition made in the form of Harshas friend. After being scared in the old, relatively low-budget flat in Avunu-1, the young couple are all gung-ho about nocturnal as well as day-time romance alike (in one scene, a lip-lock is hindered by an unromantic glass pane), having seemingly forgotten all about their recent near-death experience. So much so, when Mohini says Raju mallee vachadu, Harsha shouts back, saying Clear ga chepu. What? Seriously?    </p><p>In the first part we saw how a newly married couple was prevented by the spirit of Raju from consummating their marriage. He wants to possess the good husband and in his lecherous mission, he was aided by a foolhardy husband who forced his wife to stay in the flat despite she being devastated and extremely frightened. That was Part-I. Here you have a camera-woman who can capture a spirit and presumably even change the world asking Mohini to do the unthinkable.    </p><p>Part-II is a sorry repetition of the first part, but the novelty of the concept is badly over-used to the point of looking jaded. There is the same leering away at a nude Mohini while she is bathing, there is the same pulling off the rug while the couple is sleeping, there are the same attempts to undress her (this time by the good husband, too), there is the same technology-enabled hint that a third entity is roaming about.    </p><p>Whereas in the first part Gods power could not defeat the evil, here it succeeds for good part. The evil spirit may well leave the world exactly after one year, not a single minute delayed. Or, so we think. It strikes back, in another locality, at Prabhas Sreenus curses.    </p><p>Screenplay-wise, this is definitely not in the same league as Ravi Babus other films. While presenting the new element of a drunkard neighbor who with his bizarre tantrums and loving affection towards his wife (he says bangaram to her, at all times) presents a dichotomous picture, Ravi Babu scores on the concept but surely fails on the treatment . One waits for something interesting about his story and the climax doesnt disappoint. The couple is played by Nikita and a well-known character artiste.    </p><p>Just to make sure Sanjjanas incredible camera is established in the audiences mind, Ravi Babu goes for a scene that borders on the stupid, both idea-wise and execution-wise.    </p><p>The hi-tech apartment is a visual treat for sure. The scene where Harshas friend explains the features like a salesman could have been avoided.    </p><p>Ravi Babu banks on some voyeuristic moments here and there. There is no intelligence in story-telling and enlisting a spiritual camera cant be called innovative. If that is his idea of coming up with something akin to what Villa-2 or the recent Pisachi had, then it is disappointing.    </p><p>In a sequel like this, having the characters behave more intelligently makes all the difference. What do Hasha and Mohini do with their hands-on experience of dealing with the spirit?    </p><p>The performances are on the same lines. Poorna looks less glamorous and Harsha is ok.    </p><p>Verdict: Sans intelligent story-telling, Avunu-2 entertains only in bits and pieces. Good RR and cinematography notwithstanding, the film is more of the same. Even at 107 minutes, the film woks only in bits and pieces.    </p><p>Rating: 2.25/5                               </p>
```

and my label contain value like as

```
<p>The potential of a geographically mobile spirit is vast. When Ravi Babu (playing the spirit) made a surreptitious visit to the police station eavesdropping on Mohinis (Poorna) complaint, comfortably seated next to her, it was clear that the spirit was here to say as its freedom of movement cant be restricted by whatever means. In Avunu-2, it (or, should we say he because the spirit is a rapist?) arrives on the scene using the elevator and enters the new, upscale apartment through the main door.    </p><p>The migration-capable rapist-spirit is also tech-savvy and nothing can stop him except an amulet made in Varanasi. The characters at the receiving end, too, are the same, with an addition made in the form of Harshas friend. After being scared in the old, relatively low-budget flat in Avunu-1, the young couple are all gung-ho about nocturnal as well as day-time romance alike (in one scene, a lip-lock is hindered by an unromantic glass pane), having seemingly forgotten all about their recent near-death experience. So much so, when Mohini says Raju mallee vachadu, Harsha shouts back, saying Clear ga chepu. What? Seriously?    </p><p>In the first part we saw how a newly married couple was prevented by the spirit of Raju from consummating their marriage. He wants to possess the good husband and in his lecherous mission, he was aided by a foolhardy husband who forced his wife to stay in the flat despite she being devastated and extremely frightened. That was Part-I. Here you have a camera-woman who can capture a spirit and presumably even change the world asking Mohini to do the unthinkable.    </p><p>Part-II is a sorry repetition of the first part, but the novelty of the concept is badly over-used to the point of looking jaded. There is the same leering away at a nude Mohini while she is bathing, there is the same pulling off the rug while the couple is sleeping, there are the same attempts to undress her (this time by the good husband, too), there is the same technology-enabled hint that a third entity is roaming about.    </p><p>Whereas in the first part Gods power could not defeat the evil, here it succeeds for good part. The evil spirit may well leave the world exactly after one year, not a single minute delayed. Or, so we think. It strikes back, in another locality, at Prabhas Sreenus curses.    </p><p>Screenplay-wise, this is definitely not in the same league as Ravi Babus other films. While presenting the
```

Comment: Add your jsonDictionary result code

Comment: i edit my question SVMRAJESH

Comment: Do you want  dynamic height for rows depend upon text or have prob to fetch string

Comment: @SVMRAJESH yes i got that problem i fetch string successfully but not got  all text of my string in my label.

Comment: For that you have to set the numberOfLines; property of label

Comment: @AshokLondhe how to find my string contain how many line and how to set in label because it was dynamic.

Comment: have you used the textview in cell? i ask because there is different method for find height of the text view

Comment: i have used textview in cell

Comment: @chiragshah no, i not use textview in my cell it is label.

Comment: @AshokLondhe but i not want to textview to scroll then how i set frame or content size of scrollview please help me.

Comment: you have to first find the total no of charters in single line and then for that you can calculate no of lines and you can dynamically return no of lines

Comment: Please tell me what you have to do exactly

Comment: In your code clearly display that you used textview and there is no lable

Comment: @chiragshah Ok give me solution if i use textview in my cell how to set it dynamic size.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code:

```
+ (CGFloat)heightForText:(NSString *)text labelWidth:(float)labelWidth font:(UIFont *)font
{
    if(!text || labelWidth == 0 || !font)
        return 0.0f;

    NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName:font};
    CGSize size = CGSizeMake(labelWidth, 9999);

    CGRect rect = [text boundingRectWithSize:size options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:attributes context:nil];
    CGSize textSize = rect.size;

    return textSize.height;
}
```

Also change your rows height using -tableview:heightForRowAtindexPath method using the above method.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this solution:**

**Step 1 :** Calculate you label height depend upon your text by using this method.

```
- (CGFloat)heightForText:(NSString *)text labelWidth:(float)labelWidth font:(UIFont *)font
{
    CGSize size = CGSizeMake(labelWidth, 9999);
    NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName:font};
    CGRect rect = [text boundingRectWithSize:size options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:attributes context:nil];
    float textHeight = rect.size.height;
    return textHeight;
}
```

**Step 2 :** Set table cell height

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifierTwo=@"CellThree";
    LargeTableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifierTwo];

    NSString *txt = [[self.jsonDictionary valueForKey:@"review"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cellheight + [self heightForText:txt labelWidth:cell.largeTextView.frame.size.width font:largeTextView.font];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
- (CGSize)heightForText:(NSString *)text Width:(float)expectedWidth Font:(UIFont *)font
{
    CGSize size = CGSizeMake(labelWidth, 9999);
   UITextView *text = [[UITextView alloc]init];
    [text setFont:font];
    [text setText:str];
    return [text sizeThatFits:size];

}
```

and called this in heightForRowAtIndex

```
  - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {

        NSString *txt = [[self.jsonDictionary valueForKey:@"review"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        return cellheight + [self heightForText:txt Width:cell.largeTextView.frame.size.width Font:(UIFont *)largeTextView.font];
    }
```